How to disable SLF4 in Sqldelight?
I am using sqldelight v2.0.1 with sqlite on the JVM. When I run the application, I always get the following log lines:
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

My application is a CLI tool and I don't want these messages to appear to the end user. I already tried to manually add SLF4J as a dependency in Gradle (as stated in the help page mentioned in the log) but it did not work.
Is there any way I can disable this kind of logs?

Here's what I did to stop the StaticLoggerBinder logs. I know you said you tried this, but maybe it was the wrong version, or added to the wrong classpath. Whatever the case, this worked for me just today. I no longer get the warning when running unit tests, which was my issue.

./gradlew app:dependencies | grep slf4j, where app is my module name.
Note the version listed. For SqlDelight's sqlite-driver 2.0.2, it is org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36.
In my app module's build.gradle.kts, I added: testImplementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.36")

Obviously, if you're getting this log outside of the test classpath, add the dependency as implementation(...) or debugImplementation(...) as the case may be. Hope that helps.
